# Ntpd sets the sys time to the year 2156 after syncing to primary server

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I have a couple boards that are setup to get time from another board as the source of truth.

The primary has correct time, but when the other supporting boards attempt to sync to it, they select the primary server and everything seems fine. However, the date they yield is completely wrong. It is **not** setting the primary server as a false ticker or anything like that. Even when the times between all the boards are the same to start with, the moment the secondary boards select the primary board as the true source of time, they yield this incorrect date. It also does not set the hardware clock to the date because hwclock will error out if an attempt is made to sync the following time to it.

#### Example

```
date
Fri Dec 24 05:17:51 UTC 2156
```

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*{PRIMARY}        {IP}        6 u   13   32  377    0.307   +0.051   0.036
```

This is the source I am using to compile and run ntpd.

`www.eecis.udel.edu/\~ntp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/ntp-4.2.8p15.tar.gz`

running `ntpdate -u primary` WORKS and fixes the problem until reboot, but ntpd always yields something of the year 2156 on its own. I am very confused.

#### Configurations

```
server PRIMARY iburst minpoll 3 maxpoll 5
fudge PRIMARY stratum 2 time1 0.0 refid PRIMARY
```

Comment: This is supposed to be a comment but I am new so I can’t comment on other people’s posts yet. 1. What os/version are you running? 2. Is it possible you have chrony running?

Comment: Its a yocto OS and chrony is not on the system. However, I did uninstall ntpd and installed chrony in its place and that doesnt seem to have the same issue. I would still like to keep ntpd though if I can.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire ntpd.conf file?

Comment: Also just to clarify, when you state that running `ntpdate -u priimary`  "works", the time date and year are all current and the year is not 2156? And that only after a reboot, it goes back to the year 2156? is the `ntpd` service enabled? What board are you using? could it be that the hardware clock needs to be in sync with the system clock?

Comment: Run `ntpq -c peer <peer>` on the client & server and see what it gives. And try additional commands and see what is returned. I would also be installing `ntpsec everywhere as that seems to be where most development is going into. Please also update the source of time on the server.

Comment: Luna - Yes, ntpd is enabled by default, only ntpd is there, no chrony. Older version of ntpd appeared to work fine on the same hardware but after an upgrade it appeared to break. Running ntpdate -u primary does fix the boards time and it will continue to work just fine afterwords, but I'd like it to work with just ntpd on its own.

Comment: Bib - running ntpq -c peer primary on the secondary board actually yield a timed out error. However going the other way, primary board to secondary, on the primary board ntpq -c peer secondary it gives me the table and it says its selected the primary board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ntp era began in 1900 and lasts 2^32-1 seconds which is about 136.1 years.  It looks like your system choose the wrong era.  This is usually because the RTC battery is dead or you do not have one at all (starting in 2004).  One fix is a buddy epoch--see page 9 and 216 in "Computer Network Time Synchronization: The Network Time Protocol" by Dr. Mills.

Comment: Outside the book is there any online documentation on setting up a buddy epoch? I am kind of at a loss in searching for it.

Comment: Also though its very peculiar to me that ntpd fails with this wrong epoch, but chrony manages fine. I am actually planning just to switch, but I would rather just do a tiny fix rather than move packages around if I can

Comment: It was the RTC for the PRIMARY that was bad. Replacing that did the trick NTPD was fine.